# how to check a user given string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
  printf("Enter:");
  scanf("%5s",s); //s == abcde

  if(s == "abcde")
  printf("Yes");
  else
  printf("NO");
  
  return 0;
}
```

I want to check the user given input as above. but it always gives the output as 'NO'. what did i do wrong?

Comment: OT: You need 6 chars for `s`, that is one more char for the null terminator. But anyway it's pretty pointless to allocate a fixed amount of memory, you can as well have `char s[6];` .

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of functions in `string.h` that do that.

Most common is `strcmp()`

`int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)`.

If `s1` is identical to `s2`, `strcmp()` shall return 0.

```
  if(strcmp(s, "abcde") == 0)
    printf("Yes");
```

There is also `strncmp()`, if you want to compare at most `n` bytes of `s1` with `s2`.

Your `malloc()` call is wrong, you need one extra byte to handle `\0`.
You can also skip `sizeof(char)` since its guaranteed to be **1**, and [you don't have to type cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

```
char *s = malloc(5 + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcmp from string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
  char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
  printf("Enter:");
  scanf("%5s",s); //s == abcde

  if(strcmp(s, "abcde") == 0)
    printf("Yes");
  else
    printf("NO");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also: he doesn't allocate enough space for `s`.